# MVC Form which sends data from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I created a page which is returning simple news(Title,Author and Message) from models. I also want to create a simple form which will add a comment. News and form which adds comments is on the same view. I want my form to be a little smart and returning only one textbox for message of a comment if user is authenticated, otherwise this form should show another textbox, where user can write his name. This form should also send an id of news. This id is stored in model. I tried to return an Author name as you can see, but it seems to be wrongly coded. Maybe I will fix it by adding @User name in controller, but I dont know how to pass news id to controller from this view.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
@Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
<fieldset> 
    <legend>Message</legend> 
    @if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
    { Model.Nadawca = @User.Identity.Name.ToString(); }
    else
    {

    <div class="editor-label"> 
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nadawca)
    </div> 
    <div class="editor-field"> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nadawca) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nadawca) 
    </div>
    }
            <div class="editor-label"> 
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tresc)
    </div> 
    <div class="editor-field"> 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tresc) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tresc) 
    </div>
            <p> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send" /> 
    </p> 
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you can add a Hidden with the id, if your Model has it:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idNews)
```

Or your can use other less strongly typed version:

```
@Html.Hidden("IdNews", ViewBag.idNews)
```

It is not clear in your question where do you have the information (the ID) to display... what is sure is that to be posted you need to place an input to this data (a Hidden can do that hidding the field from users).

Comment: I need it to add a comment to database as a reference to current news. Comment needs news id to create this reference in controller